Power over Fiber wattage equivalent
with development of power over fiber; what's the equivalent "Wattage" in a given fiber optic bundle? How much (diameter) optical bundle would be needed to transmit equivalent wattage of power
(Kilowatt, etc)

I'd imagine it's pretty much the same as wire. The fiber will have some optical efficiency, and any loss will turn to heat. This heat will raise the bundle temp, and it will have some limit above which the cable will fail. There might be some special limits at the termination too, since I'd imagine losses might be concentrated there.
